# Why am I getting "TypeError" for Device function in pennylane?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, quantum-computing

I am doing basic coding for rotation of qubit as given in the Xanadu Pennylane tutorial. I have installed pennylane and tried running the code but I am getting TypeError.

I also tried with

```
dir(qml)
```

This gave me a list of built-in functions in qml where Device is already present.

Here goes the actual code:

```
from pennylane import numpy as np
import pennylane as qml

dev1 = qml.Device('default.qubit', wires=1)
```

All I am getting is the TypeError.

> TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Device with abstract
>   methods apply, author, expval, name, observables, operations,
>   pennylane_requires, reset, short_name, version

Comment: i think you might benefit by looking here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64701587/colab-running-pennylane-with-deviceerror
or here
https://discuss.pennylane.ai/t/error-when-calling-device/259/35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried running this code myself, but looking at the qubit rotation [tutorial](https://pennylane.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/qubit_rotation.html) and [example](https://github.com/XanaduAI/pennylane/blob/master/examples/Q1_qubit-rotation.py), both of them use

```
dev1 = qml.device('default.qubit', wires=1)
```

(with `device` starting with lowercase `d`)

Comment: Tried with that as well. It gives import error
`ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

Comment: It worked for me. Did you upgrade pennylane?